# Variable lookup: Why is ** with variables so much slower than with values

Tags: python, performance

I've read about `math.sqrt` being faster than `**` and today I tried. But the interesting thing wasn't the time difference between those two but the time difference between `**` with variables and `**` with values:

```
value1 = 10.1
value2 = 0.5
%timeit value1 ** value2
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 645 ns per loop
%timeit 10.1 ** 0.5
# 10000000 loops, best of 3: 60.7 ns per loop
```

This is more than ten times faster. While for the math-function the timings are almost identical (only few ns more for the variable lookup):

```
import math
%timeit math.sqrt(10.1)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 529 ns per loop
%timeit math.sqrt(value1)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 568 ns per loop
```

Could anyone explain why the variable lookup makes such a huge difference for `**` while it makes little difference for `math.sqrt`?

Setting:

- python 3.5
- Windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using variables:

```
In [41]: def var():
   ....:     value1 ** value2
   ....:     

In [43]: dis.dis(var)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (value1)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (value2)
              6 BINARY_POWER
              7 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

Using immediate values:

```
In [44]: def imm():
   ....:     10.1 ** 0.5
   ....:     

In [45]: dis.dis(imm)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (3.1780497164141406)
              3 POP_TOP
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Turns out that the compiler outsmarted us and calculated the power beforehand.

Comment: Very good to know that such operations are performed beforehand. That really surprised me but it makes sense. Do you happen to know when these are calculated? Because normally `%timeit` prints a message if one run takes much longer than the others and this wasn't the case.

Comment: Compile time, so no warning from `%timeit`, since it runs the same `LOAD_CONST` over and over.